# RelativeLayout containing a webview and another relativelayout

Tags: android

I am trying to make an `Activity` that has a `WebView` and a small bar at the bottom with height of `40dp` which has buttons for refresh, back, forward, etc. The issue i'm facing is that I want the `WebView` to consume the height of the entire view except for the bottom `40dp`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/id_web_view_browser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_example"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above is what I have so far... Right now the browser has height of the whole screen with the `RelativeLayout` at the bottom (covering a piece of the browser). Is there anything else I can do to leave the bottom `40dp` for the `RelativeLayout` only?

Comment: have you tried setting the layout_height of the WebView to wrap_content?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the webview so it layout_above the 2nd relative layout.  Then change the relative layout to be aligned to parent bottom.  That ought to work

Comment: Actually came up with the same answer below

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I was able to do the below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/id_web_view_browser"
        android:layout_above="@+id/id_web_view_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_web_view_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_refresh"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the `WebView` I set the following property: `android:layout_above="@+id/id_web_view_bar"`. That kept the bottom `40dp` for the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late... however might help any other arround...

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <Button
           android:id="@+id/button_xs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_example"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/id_web_view_browser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_xs"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case theres no need specific any height for the button or other view suppose to be after the webview.